# cython.parallel cannot see the difference in speed

Tags: python, for-loop, parallel-processing, cython

I tried to use cython.parallel prange. I can only see two cores 50% being used. How can I make use of all the cores. i.e. send the loops to the cores simultaneously sharing the arrays, volume and mc_vol?

EDIT: I also edited purely sequential for-loop which is about 30 seconds faster than than cython.parallel prange version. Both of them are using one core only. Is there are way to parallelize this.

```
cimport cython
from cython.parallel import prange, parallel, threadid
from libc.stdio cimport sprintf
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
cimport numpy as np

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef MC_Surface(np.ndarray[np.int_t,ndim=3] volume, np.ndarray[np.float32_t,ndim=3] mc_vol):
     cdef int vol_len=len(volume)-1
     cdef int k, j, i
     cdef char* pattern # a string pointer - allocate later
     Perm_area = {
            "00000000": 0.000000,
            ...
            "00011101": 1.515500
        }

         try:
         pattern = <char*>malloc(sizeof(char)*260)
         for k in range(vol_len):
             for j in range(vol_len):
                for i in range(vol_len):
                    sprintf(pattern, "%i%i%i%i%i%i%i%i",
                            volume[i, j, k],
                            volume[i, j + 1, k],
                            volume[i + 1, j, k],
                            volume[i + 1, j + 1, k],
                            volume[i, j, k + 1],
                            volume[i, j + 1, k + 1],
                            volume[i + 1, j, k + 1],
                            volume[i + 1, j + 1, k + 1]);

                    mc_vol[i, j, k] = Perm_area[pattern]
                # if Perm_area[pattern] > 0:
            #    print pattern, 'Area: ', Perm_area[pattern]
            #total_area += Perm_area[pattern]
    finally:
        free(pattern)
return mc_vol
```

EDIT following DavidW's suggestion, but prange is considerably slower:

```
 cpdef MC_Surface(np.ndarray[np.int_t,ndim=3] volume, np.ndarray[np.float32_t,ndim=3] mc_vol):
     cdef int vol_len=len(volume)-1
     cdef int k, j, i
     cdef char* pattern # a string pointer - allocate later
     Perm_area = {
            "00000000": 0.000000,
            ...
            "00011101": 1.515500
        }

        with nogil,parallel():
           try:
             pattern = <char*>malloc(sizeof(char)*260)
             for k in prange(vol_len):
                 for j in range(vol_len):
                    for i in range(vol_len):
                        sprintf(pattern, "%i%i%i%i%i%i%i%i",
                                volume[i, j, k],
                                volume[i, j + 1, k],
                                volume[i + 1, j, k],
                                volume[i + 1, j + 1, k],
                                volume[i, j, k + 1],
                                volume[i, j + 1, k + 1],
                                volume[i + 1, j, k + 1],
                                volume[i + 1, j + 1, k + 1]);
                        with gil:
                            mc_vol[i, j, k] = Perm_area[pattern]
                            # if Perm_area[pattern] > 0:
                            #    print pattern, 'Area: ', Perm_area[pattern]
                            #    total_area += Perm_area[pattern]
           finally:
               free(pattern)

        return mc_vol
```

My setup file looks like:

```
setup(
    name='SurfaceArea',
    ext_modules=[
        Extension('c_marchSurf', ['c_marchSurf.pyx'], include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
                  extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp'], extra_link_args=['-fopenmp'], language="c++")
    ],
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext}, requires=['Cython', 'numpy', 'matplotlib', 'pathos', 'scipy', 'cython.parallel']
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `with gil:`, which defines a block which can only run on one core at once. You aren't doing anything else inside the loop so you shouldn't really expect any speed-up.

In order to avoid using the GIL you need to avoid using Python features where possible. You avoid it in the string formatting part by using c `sprintf` to create your string. For the dictionary lookup part, the easiest thing is probably to use the C++ standard library, which contains a `map` class with similar behaviour. *(Note that you'll now need to compile it with Cython's C++ mode)*

```
# at the top of your file
from libc.stdio cimport sprintf
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from libcpp.map cimport map
from libcpp.string cimport string
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

# ... code omitted  ....
cpdef MC_Surface(np.ndarray[np.int_t,ndim=3] volume, np.ndarray[np.float32_t,ndim=3] mc_vol):
    # note above I've defined volume as a numpy array so that
    # I can do fast, GIL-less direct array lookup
    cdef char* pattern # a string pointer - allocate later

    Perm_area = {} # some dictionary, as before

    # depending on the size of Perm_area, this conversion to
    # a C++ object is potentially quite slow (it involves a lot
    # of string copies)
    cdef map[string,float] Perm_area_m = Perm_area

    # ... code omitted ...
    with nogil,parallel():
       try:
         # assigning pattern here makes it thread local
         # it's assigned once per thread which isn't too bad
         pattern = <char*>malloc(sizeof(char)*50)
         # when you allocate pattern you need to make it big enough
         # either by calculating a size, or by just making it overly big

         # ... more code omitted...
           # then later, inside your loops
           sprintf(pattern, "%i%i%i%i%i%i%i%i", volume[i, j, k],
                        volume[i, j + 1, k],
                        volume[i + 1, j, k],
                        volume[i + 1, j + 1, k],
                        volume[i, j, k + 1],
                        volume[i, j + 1, k + 1],
                        volume[i + 1, j, k + 1],
                        volume[i + 1, j + 1, k + 1]);
           # and now do the dictionary lookup without the GIL
           # because we're using the C++ class instead.
           # Unfortunately, we also need to do a string copy (which might slow things down)
           mc_vol[i, j, k] = Perm_area_m[string(pattern)]
           # be aware that this can throw an exception if the
           # pattern does not match (same as Python).
       finally:
         free(pattern)
```

I've also had to change volume to being a numpy array, since if it were just a Python object I'd need the GIL to index its elements.

(**Edit**: changed to take the dictionary lookup out of the GIL block too by using C++ map)

Comment: I see a speed up on my normal tripple for-loops without any prange and parallel. I used pattern = <char*>malloc(sizeof(char)*50) and springf before pattern. If the volume.shape= 400^3 then time is 42 seconds but for prange from cython.parallel the time is 75 seconds and just one CPU is active.  I edited the original post with modifications based on your suggestions.

Comment: I suspect the main speedup from my changes was actually through using pattern as a numpy array, and sprintf makes pretty little difference. I suspect that unless you can eliminate the GIL for your dictionary lookup you may struggle to get any improvement (there will be a reasonably big overhead for moving in and out of the `with gil` block.

Comment: The one thing you might try to remove the GIL from the dictionary lookup is to convert it to a C++ `map` (see http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#standard-library). I don't think I provide code for that now, so try it yourself, but I can come back to it in a day or so if you haven't worked it out...

Comment: @pyculearn I've edited it to do the dictionary lookup as using a C++ map instead of a Python dictionary, which should let the whole thing run in parallel. I don't actually know if it will be any faster (I don't think I have enough information to sensibly test it).

Comment: Thank you so much @DavidW. I am trying to use your suggestion. I am trying to resolve this error: c_marchSurf.so -fopenmp
ld: library not found for -lgomp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1

Comment: The library is for OpenMP, which is what Cython uses to parallelise things. I'm a bit surprised you didn't run into this before, since it should have needed it then too. I believe clang doesn't (yet) support OpenMP. Your options are: 1) Use a recent version of GCC or MSVC. 2) Install a modified version of Clang which does support OpenMP (https://clang-omp.github.io/). I don't think I can help you much with either of those options.